# previous scanned map areas disappeared

Tags: slam, navigation, frontier-exploration, move-base, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am using rtabmap_ros for SLAM and frontier_exploration for exploration. The problems are as followed:

1). The map will not be updated, where there are no obstacles.

2).  the previous scanned map areas between the obstacles disappeared.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215511/previous-scanned-map-areas-disappeared/) by [vonyud](https://answers.ros.org/users/22765/vonyud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using laser scans? You can also check the 3D map projection `/rtabmap/proj_map` from the Kinect, which fills empty spaces by detecting the floor.

For the map created from laser scans (`/rtabmap/grid_map`), by default only empty cells between the robot and the obstacles are set as "Empty". If the laser doesn't hit anything, the cells remain "Unknown". On version [0.10.5](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/fbb16158af7c868ff4ccb651076573309622adc2), the parameter `grid_unknown_space_filled` can be used:

```
<node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap">
    [...]
    <param name="grid_unknown_space_filled" type="bool"   value="true"/>
</node>
```

The unknown space between the obstacles should then be filled  by "Empty" cells, up to laser scan range.

There is also the parameter `map_filter_radius` that can make some parts of the map disappearing, you can set to 0 to disable the node filtering. See [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) doc.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0